# setObservers goes into NetworkStatus.ERROR right away even though results are not null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have this recycler view that I'm trying to populate with the results from an API. In my remote data source I have configured the SUCCESS and ERROR cases just in case but no matter what and even though the results do load (as my logcat shows), on setObservers it just goes to NetworkStatus.ERROR and the data is not displayed.

I don't know why this is happening, any ideas would help.

This is the remote data source:

```
class CarsRemoteDataSource {
   fun getCarsList(networkResponse: NetworkResponse<List<Cars>>) {
       val service = RetrofitService.instance
           .create(CarsService::class.java)
           .getCarsList()

       service.enqueue(object : Callback<CarsListResponse> {
           override fun onResponse(
               call: Call<CarsListResponse>,
               response: Response<CarsListResponse>
           ) {Movie
               val resource = response.body()?.run {
                   if (results.isNotEmpty())
                       Resource(NetworkStatus.SUCCESS, results)
                   else
                       Resource(NetworkStatus.ERROR)
               } ?: run {
                   Resource(NetworkStatus.ERROR)
               }
               networkResponse.onResponse(resource)
           }

           override fun onFailure(call: Call<CarsListResponse>, t: Throwable) {
               networkResponse.onResponse(Resource(NetworkStatus.ERROR, message = t.message))
           }
       })
   }


}

interface NetworkResponse<T> {
   fun onResponse(value: Resource<T>)
}
```

This is the activity where I run to that error:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var  binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val cars = mutableListOf<Cars>()
    private lateinit var recyclerAdapter: RecyclerAdapter

    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels(
        factoryProducer = {MainViewModelFactory()}
    )

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setObservers()
        initRecyclerView()


    }

    private fun initRecyclerView() {
        with(binding.rvCars){
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            recyclerAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(cars).apply {
                setCarsList(cars)
            }
            adapter = recyclerAdapter
        }
    }

    private fun setObservers(){
        viewModel.carsList.observe(this, Observer {
            when(it.status){
                NetworkStatus.LOADING ->{
                    //show loading state
                    Toast.makeText(this,"LOADING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                }
                NetworkStatus.SUCCESS -> {
                    //hide loading state

                    //render character list
                    Log.d("DATA NOT RECEIVED: ","$cars")
                    it.data?.let { it1 -> recyclerAdapter.setCarsList(it1) }
                    Log.d("DATA IN DATA: ", "${it.data}")
                    recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }

                NetworkStatus.ERROR -> {
                    //show error message
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Error loading content", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    //hide loading state

                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

API Response:

```
data class CarsListResponse(
    val results: List<Cars>
)

data class Cars(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String
)
```

Excerpt from API response when code is run:

```
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: age: 5338
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: {"page":1,"results":[{"id":1,"name":"Volvo"},{"id":2,"name":"Toyota"},{"id":2,"name":"Ford"}],"total_pages":500,"total_results":10000}
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- END HTTP (13231-byte body)
```

Comment: What is the response of API?

Comment: @PriyankaRajput I added it

Comment: You did not added it, you need to add the `throwable.toString()` value to get the exception message

Comment: This is not API response, Its just a model class that you added recently. What you are getting after hitting the API

Comment: @PriyankaRajput Oh, if you meant when the code is run, then now I did add it.

Comment: @MatPag Where am I suppose to add that line though?